# TSQL challenge to join and union in one step, is it pssble?

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to make single datasource which will have several data types which later will be ID'ed in our BI application (and I can NOT change anything), each  type ID'ed by column ***Type*** like in example below, so basically I have 2 tables which I want join/union at the same time, I tried to play with join, and could not make it work so fare.  Do you think it's doable ??  THere is some dynamic going on in input tables so it's hard to go with preset columns which will serve all tables. 
This is my input:

```
;WITH cte1 AS (SELECT 'A' type, 'alpha1' rec1, 'bravo1' rec2 UNION
SELECT 'A' type, 'alpha2' rec1, 'bravo2' rec2 UNION
SELECT 'A' type, 'alpha3' rec1, 'bravo3' rec2 )
, cte2 AS (
SELECT 'X' type, 'zulu01' recX UNION
SELECT 'X' type, 'zulu02' rexX )
```

and this is wanted output

```
;WITH cteWanted AS (SELECT 'A' type, 'alpha1' rec1, 'bravo1' rec2, NULL recX UNION
SELECT 'A' type, 'alpha2' rec1, 'bravo2' rec2, NULL recX UNION
SELECT 'A' type, 'alpha3' rec1, 'bravo3' rec2, NULL recX UNION 
SELECT 'X' type, NULL rec1, NULL rec2, 'zulu01' recX  UNION  
SELECT 'X' type, NULL rec1, NULL rec2, 'zulu02' recX )

SELECT * FROM cteTarget
```

[image]

Comment: How did you try to `union` `cte1` and `cte2`? `select [type], rec1, rec2, Cast( NULL as VarChar(10) ) as recX from cte1 union all select [type], NULL, NULL, recX from cte2`?

Comment: HI Habo, surely it will work, but column set  is changing in my case, so I try go with something different and pref not dynamic sql.

Comment: perhaps you can explain to us how did Rec1, rec2, recx come up with those values. is this sql-server?

Comment: I'd like to refer to column list with wild card, cte1.*

Answer (score 0):

Tx all, I realized that I need to go with HABO solution.